# How to use sed to insert a line before each line in a file with the original line's content surrounding by a string?

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to use sed (GNU sed version 4.2.1) to insert a line before each line in a file with that line's content surrounding by a string.

**Input:**

```
truncate table ALPHA;
truncate table BETA;
delete from TABLE_CHARLIE where ID=1;
```

**Expected Result:**

```
SELECT 'truncate table ALPHA;' from dual;
truncate table ALPHA;
SELECT 'truncate table BETA;' from dual;
truncate table BETA;
SELECT 'delete from TABLE_CHARLIE where ID=1;' from dual;
delete from TABLE_CHARLIE where ID=1;
```

I have tried to make use of the ampersand (&) special character, but this does not seem to work.  If I put anything after the ampersand on the replacement string, the output is not correct.

Attempt 1:

```
sed -e "s/\(.*\)/SELECT '&\n&/g" input.txt

output:
SELECT 'truncate table ALPHA;
truncate table ALPHA;
SELECT 'truncate table BETA;
truncate table BETA;
SELECT 'delete from TABLE_CHARLIE where ID=1;
delete from TABLE_CHARLIE where ID=1;
```

With the preceding code, I get the `SELECT '` as expected, but once I attempt to add `' from dual;` to the right side of string, things get out of whack.

Attempt 2:

```
sed -e "s/\(.*\)/SELECT '&' from dual;\n&/g"  input.txt

output:
' from dual;cate table ALPHA;
truncate table ALPHA;
' from dual;cate table BETA;
truncate table BETA;
SELECT 'delete from TABLE_CHARLIE where ID=1;' from dual;
```

Comment: This works here. Maybe check for hidden (non-printable) characters in your command line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can take advantage of the hold space to temporarily store the original line.

```
sed "h;s/.*/'SELECT '&' from dual;/;p;g" input.txt
```

or more readably:

```
sed "
h
s/.*/'SELECT '&' from dual;/
p
g" input.txt
```

Here's a breakdown of the command.

1. First, each line of the input is placed in the *pattern* space.
2. The `h` command copies the contents of the pattern space to the *hold* space.
3. The `s` command performs a substitution on the pattern space. The `&` represents whatever was matched. This command leaves the hold space unaffected.
4. The `p` command outputs the contents of the pattern space to standard output.
5. The `g` command copies the contents of the hold space to the pattern space.
6. By default, the contents of the pattern space are written to standard output before reading the next input line.

---

As Glenn Jackman points out, you can replace `p;g` with `G`. This builds up a two-line value in the pattern space that is then printed, rather than print two separate pattern spaces.

```
sed "h;s/.*/'SELECT '&' from dual;/;G" input.txt
```

Also, you can add comments to the `sed` command so that you can understand what the line noise does later :), if this is in a script.

```
sed " 
# The input line is first copied to the pattern space

h                               # Copy the pattern space to the hold space
s/.*/'SELECT '&' from dual;/    # Modify the pattern space
p                               # Print the (modified) pattern space
g                               # Copy the hold space to the pattern space

# The output of the pattern space (the original input line) is now printed
" input.txt
```

Comment: Nice answer. You can use `G` in place of `p;g`. [ref](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Other-Commands.html#Other-Commands)

Comment: @glennjackman Thanks; my working knowledge of `sed` is pretty weak. I know some of the high-level concepts, but few of the details.

Comment: of course, no need to memorize the seldom-used features. That's why I bookmark the bash/gawk/sed manuals.

Answer (score 1):

Your second attempt works on both 4.2.1 and 4.2.2 versions of sed. I received same invalid input when I tried to save your input file with windows line endings (line feed and carriage return).

Use this command on your input file before running your sed command:

```
tr -d '\15\32' < winfile.txt > unixfile.txt
```

Or as you suggest, simply by using the `dos2unix` utility.

Comment: The windows format of the input file was the problem.  Instead of using the td' command which works as you suggested, I just did a 'dos2unix' command on the file running the 'Attempt 2' sed statement.

Comment: dos2unix is also a good way, but may not be present by default on every unix platform, so I rather suggested `tr`.

Comment: Also, If your problem is already resolved you should mark the answer @RAMSidustle

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for an alternative to sed, these work:

```
awk '{printf "SELECT '\''%s'\'' from dual;\n%s\n", $0, $0}' file
```

```
perl -lpe "print qq{SELECT '\$_' from dual;}" file
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it with `awk`:

```
awk -v PRE="SELECT '" -v SU="' from dual;" '{print PRE$0SU; print}'`
```